# JSON dates not saving in DB

Tags: php, json, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have following date input field in my Form:

```
{{ Form::text("dob", Input::old('dob'), array('placeholder'=>'Date of Birth', 'id'=>'dob')) }}
```

My form also contains other values.
I am submitting the form using ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        url: 'StdReg',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('form#StdRegForm').serialize(),
        success: ..........
```

All the field in form are successfully stored in DB but `dob` column shows `0000-00-00`. I also tried data: `JSON.parse($('form#StdRegForm').serialize()` but of no use.

How can I store date in this format e.g. 04-07-2014 for today

Comment: MySQL's `DATE` [format is YYYY-MM-DD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html), you'll need to either [format your date](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) before you store it, or [format your date as you store it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: You are right I was actually mean to get date from user in d-m-y format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`04-07-2014` is not the standard MySQL DATE format (`YYYY-MM-DD`)

You can easily convert it to the required format using PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) library:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', Input::get('dob'));
// 'd-m-Y' is 04-07-2014 format 
$formatted = $date->format('Y-m-d'); // save as MySQL DATE
```

Now you have a properly formatted string for MySQL, use it in your query. You obviously need to produce the inverse procedure when retriving it back from the DB, something like

```
echo DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $savedDate)->format('d-m-Y');
```